# Looking for a Scifi short story about "the stream"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a story about a society that has access to a stream of information in their heads.  One man did not and he spent all of his time in abandoned libraries.

He was pitied until the day the stream went down.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like [Stream of Consciousness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_of_Consciousness_(The_Outer_Limits)) (episode 48) from The Outer Limits:

Per Wikipedia:

> *Due to a brain injury, Ryan Unger cannot enjoy the benefits of a neural implant that allows other people to tap into The Stream — a
> direct connection into all human knowledge. He tries, unsuccessfully,
> to keep up with everyone else by using a long-forgotten skill: reading
> books.*
>
> *Unfortunately for the human race, the Stream has been erroneously programmed to crave information instead of knowledge. Soon, it begins
> to turn the human race into its slaves to attempt to locate and
> process every single bit of information, a process that will lead to
> the Human race's extinction as people stop doing everything to obtain
> the desired information.*
>
> *Ryan's injury keeps him from falling under the sway of the Stream, leaving him the only person who can stop it. The Stream will not allow itself to be shut down, however, and it commands the humans under its control to defend itself from Ryan.*
>
> *In the end, Ryan succeeds in shutting down the Stream and saving
> mankind. Cut off from the mental crutch humanity has used for so long,
> the entire population (save Ryan) are reduced to a childlike mental
> state. Ryan finds himself needing to teach mankind the old ways of
> acquiring information again — from books.*