Book about people with implants and the main computer went down
I read a book a few years ago about people who had implants that provided them with all the knowledge they needed to know then the mainframe went down.  They had to learn how to live with out all modern technology.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  The plot you've described doesn't seem to be long enough for a book; what else happened?

This situation is one part of a couple of novels in the same series by Vernor Vinge. Humans must learn to live without the technology integrated into their brains as it no longer works in the slow zone. The first book with this problem is A Fire Upon The Deep.

Later in the series in The Children of the Sky. The children awoken from coldsleep must make a similar adjustment to thinking and looking out for themselves. Not blaming their software if they injure themselves. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10170545-the-children-of-the-sky

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/77711.A_Fire_Upon_the_Deep

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60302/looking-for-a-scifi-short-story-about-the-stream/60305#60305

The "Council Wars" series by John Ringo? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjav-jh4smFAxVxUkEAHSz5DZwQFnoECC0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fseries%2F42763-the-council-wars&usg=AOvVaw3q5lomTMbCP5tZ3Gmub7G7&opi=89978449

More detail would help here. Any additional information you can provide - when you read it, was it an old book then, what did the cover look like, short story/novella/novel, any scenes you can remember, etc. - will provide additional clues.

Sounds like an answer, @JudithJones

@Freeman I am far from confident my idea is the correct answer. Valorum posted a link to an answer which seems a better match to me.

The John Ringo books also seem a better match than my suggestion.
